# Recargar sidemenu al iniciar sesión Ionic 3, Angular 6

Tags: angular, ionic

Lo que intento hacer es que al iniciar sesión en mi app, el sidemenu se actualice y me aparezcan las opciones correspondientes según el tipo de usuario que inicio sesión.

El método para iniciar sesión es el siguiente:

```
login() {
  this.Loading("","send");
  this.http.postData(this.userData, "post/login").subscribe( result => {
   this.responseData = result;
   if (this.responseData.success) {
    localStorage.setItem('userSesion', JSON.stringify(this.responseData.dataUser));
    if (this.responseData.dataUser.tipo === '1') {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(InicioPage);
    } else if (this.responseData.dataUser.tipo === '2') {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(IniciodocentePage);
    }
   } else {
     this.Loading(this.responseData.dataUser,"error");
   }
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

En mi app.component.ts en donde están los arreglos con las opciones del menú esta de la siguiente manera:

```
export class MyApp {
 @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

 rootPage: any = HomePage;

 pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
 public sesion:boolean;
 public opt:boolean;
 userDetails:any = {};

 constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
  this.initializeApp();

  if (localStorage.getItem('userSesion')) {
   const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSesion'));
   this.userDetails = data;
   this.sesion = true;
   if (this.userDetails.tipo == '1') {
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Inicio', component: InicioPage },
      { title: 'Registro de Inscripción', component: CarrerasestudiantePage },
      { title: 'Historial Academico', component: HistoricoPage },
      { title: 'Procesar Inscripción', component: ProcesarinscripcionPage }
    ];
   } else if (this.userDetails.tipo == '2') {
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Inicio', component: IniciodocentePage },
      { title: 'Mi Carga Académica', component: CargaacademicaprofesorPage }
    ];
   }
 } else {
   this.pages = [
     { title: 'Entrar', component: HomePage },
     { title: 'Olvide mi clave', component: AboutPage },
     { title: 'Consultar Estatus', component: ContactPage }
   ];
   this.sesion = false;
 }
}

initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  });
}

 openPage(page) {
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
 }
}
```

El problema es que cuando inicio sesión me siguen apareciendo las opciones en el menú que tengo antes de iniciar sesión. Si presiono F5 ahí si se recarga el sidemenu y me aparecen las opciones correspondientes según el tipo de usuario.

Comment: Yo usaría un Event https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ . Al hacer login disparas el publish y te suscribes en la pagina donde tienes los items del menú.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un servicio que maneje la sesión del usuario y en este crear observable al que las vistas y otros servicios se conecten. Así cuando haya cambios en el usuario hacer un refresh para que se actualice en todo los componentes conectados. (En mi caso yo tengo un modelo de usuario tener mejor contorl de los datos)

user.model.ts

```
export class User {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    tokens: Array<Token> = [];

    constructor(username, password, email = '') {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}

//user.service.ts   

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
export class UserService {

    user: User;
    private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.user);

    // Lo demas componentes se ponen a la esucha de cambio
    // a través de esté método
    getUserObservable(): Observable<User> {
        return this.userSubject.asObservable();
    }

  // Este método se usa para enviar los cambios a todos los componentes a la escucha
  private setUser(user: User) {
      this.user = user;
      // Refrescar user en los observables
      this.userSubject.next(this.user);
   }
}
```

menu.ts

```
import {UserService} from 'user.service'

export class Menu {

    user: User;

    constructor(userService:UserService){
        // REGISTRASE AL OBSERVABLE DE UserService
        // para estar a la escucha de cambios de user
        this.userService.getUserObservable().subscribe(
        (data) => {
           this.user = data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Cuando tuve un problema similar usé este link como referencia http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/05/comunicacion-servicio-componente-en-angular.html

(Si encuentro el otro que use te lo agrego como comentario)

Comment: Este link está mejor explicado por si te sirve https://blog.ng-classroom.com/blog/tips/data-sharing-in-multi-view/